# Obtaining a sine wave ECG from a matrix of short arrays

Tags: ecg, computer-graphics

I am a software developer, so please forgive my limited knowledge in the DSP space.

I am given a task to plot an ECG graph and the data I receive from an ECG (BLE) device is provided in a matrix of short arrays.

E.g:

```
[4114, 4130, 4134, 4139, 4133, 4121, 4120, 4136, 4127, 4129]
[4144, 4163, 4152, 4156, 4142, 4135, 4135, 4144, 4147, 4146]
[4131, 4127, 4141, 4131, 4147, 4144, 4141, 4154, 4181, 4168]
[4153, 4167, 4161, 4159, 4147, 4153, 4158, 4156, 4165, 4154]
```

I think I can find the sampling frequency of the device as well.

Can you guys point me to a formula I can use to get a Waveform (e.g: [a graph-library I might use has this example](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.Wpf.Examples/blob/master/v5.x/Sandbox/UsefulExamples/Examples/SweepingEcgSeries/Waveform.csv))

Update 1: I also have the followings: ADC Zero:128 & ADC Gain:500

Thank you in advance!